# Why is the amount of malocs 10 * sizeof in the outer loop and 2 * sizeof in the inner loop?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I don't understand why i must use 10 * sizeof in the outer loop and 2 * sizeof in the inner loop? In the first place i use 1 * sizof (actually just sizeof) at both but then i had a lot of errors in valgrind (810) about size of 8 etc. so i played a little with the sizes and 10 and 2 are found to be the correct sizes. How can i calculate the correct size in the future instead of guessing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int LOCATIONS = 9;
const int NUMBERS = 9;

typedef struct location {
    int column;
    int row;
    int zone;
} location;

typedef struct Number {
    int number;
    struct location *lockNum[];
} Number;

int main(void) {
            
    // Declare pointer to array structures Number.
    struct Number * numbers[NUMBERS];
    
    int i, j;

    // Memory allocation for each structure Number of array.
    for (i = 0; i < NUMBERS; ++i) {
        // It happens to have 10 * sizeof to make it work without 0 errors in valgrind but why?
        numbers[i] = (struct Number *) malloc (10 * sizeof(struct Number *));
        
        // Initialize members of structure Number.
        numbers[i]->number = 9;
        
        // Allocate memory for each location whithin structure Number of array.
        for (j = 0; j < LOCATIONS; ++j) {
            // Same here but why 2 *?
            numbers[i]->lockNum[j] = (struct location *) malloc (2 * sizeof(struct location *));
            
            // Initialize members of structure location
            numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->column = 0;
            numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->row = 0;
            numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->zone = 0;
        }   
    }

    // Do something...

    // Print content of allocated spaces.
    for (i = 0; i < NUMBERS; ++i) {
        printf("\nThere are %d possible locations for number %d\n\n", numbers[i]->number, i + 1);
        for (j = 0; j < LOCATIONS; ++j) {
            printf("location %d at row %d column %d in zone %d\n", j + 1, numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->row, numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->column, numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->zone);
        }
    }
    
    // Free memory after usage.
    for (i = 0; i < NUMBERS; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < LOCATIONS; ++j) {
            free(numbers[i]->lockNum[j]);
        }
        free(numbers[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the original author doesn't have the foggiest clue of what they're doing? `numbers[i]` refers to a pointer to `Number`. The sizing calculation of some constant (in this case 10) multiplied by the size of a pointer, e.g. `malloc (10 * sizeof(struct Number *))` is nonsense.

Comment: okey if it is nonsense why does it work on 10 and 2? I want to create an array of NUMBERS time pointers to struct Numbers and whithin that struct there must be an array of LOCATION times a pointer to struct location.

Comment: Even a blind squirrel finds a nut once in awhile. The author is literally guessing that the size of 10x pointers is sufficient to hold a `Number` structure and accommodate space for the `lockNum` flexible array member. The second case, btw, is even *worse* nonsense, since there the exact number of `Location` elements is known (e.g. one), but the author is, once again, guessing. As in, guessing that 2x the size of a pointer will be sufficient to hold a single `Location` instance.

Comment: @WhozCraig: All of the `for` loops should be counting from 0 to 8, which is 9 members, not 10.  Each array slot should be holding 1 pointer, not 2.  Regardless of the dubious use of hard-coded constants, this should work with 9 and 1.  I find myself as mystified as the OP.

Comment: OK, the problem appears to be with the freeing of the memory, not its allocation.  See https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/MealyYummyGenres#main.c, and note the "double free or corruption" error you get at the bottom of the console output.  Then comment out lines 56 through 61, run the program again, and note that the problem no longer occurs.

Comment: The memory corruption comes from not allocating enough memory, no? For each number, you must allocate space for the number plus space for each location in the flexible array.

Comment: Agree with "the author doesn't know what they're doing". The inner loop allocates enough space for 2 pointers, then it uses it as a location struct. I guess one pointer wasn't big enough to fit a location struct so they made it 2. Instead, the author should change it so it allocates enough space for a location struct.

Comment: Do you know what malloc does?

Comment: @user253751: The `LockNum` array doesn't store `location` instances; it stores pointers to `location` instances.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now.  Going off to test it.

Comment: @user253751: Refresh your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sizing of those mallocs is a stab. The data should be based on the actual sizes of the underlying types. The only tricky one is the allowance for the flexible array member of a `Number`.

Flexible array members are typically allocated using the size of the structure + N * size of the array element type. This may leave some padding/slack in its wake, but is supported nonetheless. Therefore...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

const int LOCATIONS = 9;
const int NUMBERS = 9;

typedef struct location {
    int column;
    int row;
    int zone;
} location;

typedef struct Number {
    int number;
    struct location *lockNum[];
} Number;

int main()
{
    struct Number *numbers[NUMBERS];

    for (int i=0; i<NUMBERS; ++i)
    {
        numbers[i] = malloc(sizeof **numbers + (LOCATIONS * sizeof(location*)));

        // Allocate memory for each location whithin structure Number of array.
        numbers[i]->number = LOCATIONS;
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers[i]->number; ++j) {
            numbers[i]->lockNum[j] = malloc ( sizeof(location) );
            
            // Initialize members of structure location
            numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->column = j;
            numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->row = i;
            numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->zone = 42;
        }           
    }

    // print the results
    for (int i=0; i<NUMBERS; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<numbers[i]->number; ++j)
        {
            printf("{%d %d %d} ", 
                numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->row,
                numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->column,
                numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->zone);
        }
        fputc('\n', stdout);
    }

    // free allocated spaces
    for (int i=0; i<NUMBERS; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<numbers[i]->number; ++j)
            free(numbers[i]->lockNum[j]);
        free(numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
{0 0 42} {0 1 42} {0 2 42} {0 3 42} {0 4 42} {0 5 42} {0 6 42} {0 7 42} {0 8 42} 
{1 0 42} {1 1 42} {1 2 42} {1 3 42} {1 4 42} {1 5 42} {1 6 42} {1 7 42} {1 8 42} 
{2 0 42} {2 1 42} {2 2 42} {2 3 42} {2 4 42} {2 5 42} {2 6 42} {2 7 42} {2 8 42} 
{3 0 42} {3 1 42} {3 2 42} {3 3 42} {3 4 42} {3 5 42} {3 6 42} {3 7 42} {3 8 42} 
{4 0 42} {4 1 42} {4 2 42} {4 3 42} {4 4 42} {4 5 42} {4 6 42} {4 7 42} {4 8 42} 
{5 0 42} {5 1 42} {5 2 42} {5 3 42} {5 4 42} {5 5 42} {5 6 42} {5 7 42} {5 8 42} 
{6 0 42} {6 1 42} {6 2 42} {6 3 42} {6 4 42} {6 5 42} {6 6 42} {6 7 42} {6 8 42} 
{7 0 42} {7 1 42} {7 2 42} {7 3 42} {7 4 42} {7 5 42} {7 6 42} {7 7 42} {7 8 42} 
{8 0 42} {8 1 42} {8 2 42} {8 3 42} {8 4 42} {8 5 42} {8 6 42} {8 7 42} {8 8 42}
```

Nice. Does this *really* work? Modifying the original code to use a random number in 5..10 for the number of locations at each Number would be... interesting:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

const int NUMBERS = 9;

typedef struct location {
    int column;
    int row;
    int zone;
} location;

typedef struct Number {
    int number;
    struct location *lockNum[];
} Number;

int main()
{
    struct Number *numbers[NUMBERS];

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    for (int i=0; i<NUMBERS; ++i)
    {
        int n_locations =  5 + (rand() % 6);
        numbers[i] = malloc(sizeof **numbers + (n_locations * sizeof(location*)));

        // Allocate memory for each location within structure Number of array.
        numbers[i]->number = n_locations;
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers[i]->number; ++j) {
            numbers[i]->lockNum[j] = malloc ( sizeof(location) );
            
            // Initialize members of structure location
            numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->column = j;
            numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->row = i;
            numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->zone = 42;
        }           
    }

    // print the results
    for (int i=0; i<NUMBERS; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d : ", numbers[i]->number);
        for (int j=0; j<numbers[i]->number; ++j)
        {
            printf("{%d %d %d} ", 
                numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->row,
                numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->column,
                numbers[i]->lockNum[j]->zone);
        }
        fputc('\n', stdout);
    }

    // free allocated spaces
    for (int i=0; i<NUMBERS; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<numbers[i]->number; ++j)
            free(numbers[i]->lockNum[j]);
        free(numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

**Output** (varies, obviously)

```
7 : {0 0 42} {0 1 42} {0 2 42} {0 3 42} {0 4 42} {0 5 42} {0 6 42} 
5 : {1 0 42} {1 1 42} {1 2 42} {1 3 42} {1 4 42} 
7 : {2 0 42} {2 1 42} {2 2 42} {2 3 42} {2 4 42} {2 5 42} {2 6 42} 
5 : {3 0 42} {3 1 42} {3 2 42} {3 3 42} {3 4 42} 
6 : {4 0 42} {4 1 42} {4 2 42} {4 3 42} {4 4 42} {4 5 42} 
10 : {5 0 42} {5 1 42} {5 2 42} {5 3 42} {5 4 42} {5 5 42} {5 6 42} {5 7 42} {5 8 42} {5 9 42} 
9 : {6 0 42} {6 1 42} {6 2 42} {6 3 42} {6 4 42} {6 5 42} {6 6 42} {6 7 42} {6 8 42} 
5 : {7 0 42} {7 1 42} {7 2 42} {7 3 42} {7 4 42} 
10 : {8 0 42} {8 1 42} {8 2 42} {8 3 42} {8 4 42} {8 5 42} {8 6 42} {8 7 42} {8 8 42} {8 9 42}
```

Whatever the original author was doing, gambling was involved. The above examples should provide a much better recipe for doing what you seem to be going for.

Comment: `numbers[i] = malloc(sizeof **numbers + (LOCATIONS * sizeof(location*)));` is _good_ to use `sizeof **numbers` to determine the size based on the object and not type.  Could do the same with `sizeof(location*)` --> `sizeof numbers[i]->lockNum[0]` and `numbers[i]->lockNum[j] = malloc ( sizeof(location) );` --> `malloc(sizeof numbers[i]->lockNum[j][0])`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I could indeed. Not gonna lie; I was lazy.

Answer (score 0):

In the line :

```
numbers[i] = malloc(sizeof **numbers + (LOCATIONS * sizeof(location*)))
```

You are mixing a pointer and struct. What you want to do is just allocate the locations in number[i] :

```
numbers[i] = malloc(sizeof(Number)) // create the struct numbers[i] points to
Numbers[i]->lockNums = malloc(LOCATIONS * sizeof(Location)) // alloc locations array in a second time
```